# Making a facade in Python 2.5

Tags: python

I want to have a Python class that acts as a wrapper for another Python class.

Something like this

```
class xxx:
    name = property( fset=lambda self, v: setattr(self.inner, 'name', v), fget=lambda self: getattr(self.inner, 'name' ))

    def setWrapper( self, obj )
       self.inner = obj
```

So when someone says xxx().x = 'hello' I want it to set the value on xxx().inner.whatever and not xxx().x.

Is this possible? I have been trying lambdas, but to no avail. I'm using Python 2.5

**Edit:**
Now my wife isn't rushing me to bed so I can flush out the code a bit more.  I kind of had an idea about what you guys had below, but from the [docs](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/#property) it seemed that you should avoid overriding `__setattr__/__getattr__` and use property instead.  If it is not possible to do this via the property function then I will use the `__setattr__/__getattr__`?  Thanks

Answer (score 6):

This is where you use the `__setattr__` and `__getattr__` methods as documented [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access).

In short, if you do this:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
       object.__setattr__(self, 'inner', wrapped)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.inner, attr)

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        setattr(self.inner, attr, value)
```

It should do what you're after.  I'd highly recommend reading the docs linked to above.

EDIT: As pointed out, the original version fails due to `__setattr__` being called unconditionally.  I've updated this example.  Note that this version is reliant on new-style class behaviour (as indicated by subclassing from object).  For old-style I think you'd need to mess with `__dict__` as follows:

```
class OldStyleWrapper:
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.__dict__['inner'] = wrapped

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.inner, attr)

     def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        setattr(self.inner, attr, value)
```

Answer (score 5):

As another answer said, `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` are the key, **but** you need care when using the latter...:

```
class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        object.__setattr__(self, 'inner', wrapped)

    def __getattr__(self, n):
        return getattr(self.inner, n)

    def __setattr__(self, n, value):
        setattr(self.inner, n, value)
```

You don't need precautions for `self.inner` **access**, because `__getattr__` gets called only for attributes that aren't otherwise present; but `__setattr__` gets called for EVERY attribute, so when you actually need to **set** `self.inner` (or any other attribute), you need to explicitly bypass `__setattr__` (here I'm using `object` for the purpose, so I also *inherit* from `object` -- **highly** advisable anyway, in Python 2.*, otherwise you'd be making an "old-style class" [[the kind which AT LAST disappeared in Python 3]], which you really don't want to...;-).

Answer (score 0):

I believe both Alex and Ben's answers should edit their setattr call as follows:

```
setattr(self.inner, n, value)
```