# How to share same method on two different classes in python

Tags: python, typeclass

I have class:

```
class A(object):
    def do_computing(self):
        print "do_computing"
```

Then I have:

```
new_class = type('B', (object,), {'a': '#A', 'b': '#B'})
```

What I want to achieve is to make all methods and properties on class A a member of class B. Class A can have from 0 to N such elements. I want to make them all a member of class B.

So far I get to:

```
methods = {}

for el in dir(A):
    if el.startswith('_'):
        continue

    tmp = getattr(A, el)

    if isinstance(tmp, property):
        methods[el] = tmp

    if isinstance(tmp, types.MethodType):
        methods[el] = tmp

instance_class = type('B', (object,), {'a': '#A', 'b': '#B'})

for name, func in methods.items():
    new_method = types.MethodType(func, None, instance_class)
    setattr(instance_class, name, new_method)
```

But then when I run:

```
instance().do_computing()
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: unbound method do_computing() must be called with A instance as first argument (got B instance instead)
```

Why I had to do that? We have a lot of legacy code and I need fancy objects that will pretend they are old objects but really.

One more important thing. I cannot use inheritance, to much magic happens in the background.

Comment: What's wrong with having B inherit from A?

Comment: Can't use inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do it like this, it will work:

```
import types

class A(object):
    def do_computing(self):
        print "do_computing"

methods = {name:value for name, value in A.__dict__.iteritems()
                        if not name.startswith('_')}

instance_class = type('B', (object,), {'a': '#A', 'b': '#B'})

for name, func in methods.iteritems():
    new_method = types.MethodType(func, None, instance_class)
    setattr(instance_class, name, new_method)

instance_class().do_computing()
```

Comment: This is actually something I used. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks. Note that this does not check the type of the values it copies, so they could be something other than a property or method which might cause a problem depending on what else is in `class A`. You could add additional checks to the `if` conditional portion of the list comprehension that also checked their type if you needed to limit it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, you can do this with inheritance:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
```

Then:

```
>>> b = B()
>>> b.do_computing()
```

`do_computing`

Edit: cms_mgr said the same in the comments, also fixed indentation

Comment: I hope you will fix the indentation :)

Comment: Oops. Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: I cannot use inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

are you creating a facade? maybe you want something like this:

[Making a facade in Python 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469591/python-and-a-facade)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern

you could also use delegators. here's an example from the wxpython AGW:

```
_methods = ["GetIndent", "SetIndent", "GetSpacing", "SetSpacing", "GetImageList", "GetStateImageList",
        "GetButtonsImageList", "AssignImageList", "AssignStateImageList", "AssignButtonsImageList",
        "SetImageList", "SetButtonsImageList", "SetStateImageList", 'other_methods']

def create_delegator_for(method):
"""
Creates a method that forwards calls to `self._main_win` (an instance of :class:`TreeListMainWindow`).

:param `method`: one method inside the :class:`TreeListMainWindow` local scope.
"""

    def delegate(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return getattr(self._main_win, method)(*args, **kwargs)
    return delegate

# Create methods that delegate to self._main_win. This approach allows for
# overriding these methods in possible subclasses of HyperTreeList
for method in _methods:
    setattr(HyperTreeList, method, create_delegator_for(method))
```

Note that these wrap *class* methods... i.e both functions take a signature like `def func(self, some, other, args)` and are intended to be called like `self.func(some, args)`. If you want to delegate a class function to a non-class function, you'll need to modify the delegator.

Comment: That's actually something I like to achieve more or less. Will give it a shot.

Comment: Facade is something that possibly I was looking for however, the other answer is shorter to implement, and it does a trick. I'm up-voting but as question can have only one good answer I will pick the one that I'm using. Thank you very much for your help tho.

Comment: Something like this doesn't really require any more code to implement than my answer. However, it does result in significantly greater overhead when calling the resulting delegated methods -- which might be worth it, but only if `self._main_win` needed to be changed on-the-fly later.

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit from a parent class as such:

```
class Awesome():

    def method_a():
        return "blee" 


class Beauty(Awesome):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = self.method_a()

b = Beauty()
print(b.x)
>>> "blee"
```

This was freely typed, but the logic is the same none the less and should work.

You can also do fun things with setattr like so:

```
#as you can see this class is worthless and is nothing 
class blee():
    pass 

b = blee()
setattr(b, "variable_1", "123456")
print(b.variable_1)
>>> 123456
```

essentially you can assign any object, method to a class instance with setattr.

EDIT: Just realized that you did use setattr, woops ;)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I cannot use inheritance, imagine base class has Meta, Meta is inherited and armageddon happens.